# Monotonic subsequences

Tags: analysis

Given that $a_{1}>0$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{2}{1+a_{n}}$. How could I show that the two subsequences $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k-1}$ are monotone.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: A natural thing to try is to see how $a_{n+2}$ compares with $a_n$:

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+2}&=1+\frac2{1+a_{n+1}}\\\\
&=1+\frac2{1+1+\frac2{1+a_n}}\\\\
&=1+\frac2{2+\frac2{1+a_n}}\\\\
&=1+\frac2{\frac{4+2a_n}{1+a_n}}\\\\
&=1+\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}\\\\
&=\frac{3+2a_n}{2+a_n}\\\\
&=2-\frac1{2+a_n}
\end{align*}$$

Now let $$f(x)=2-\frac1{2+x}\;,$$ and consider where $f(x)-x$ is positive and where it’s negative.

Comment: Having found where f(x)-x is positive and where it's negative, what can I say for the two subsequences??

Comment: @Mary: If you did it right, you found that it’s increasing on one side of a certain number $\alpha$ and decreasing on the other side. Show that if $x<\alpha$, then $f(x)<\alpha$, and if $x>\alpha$, then $f(x)>\alpha$.

Comment: I got stuck now... With this can I schow that the subsequence $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k-1}$ are monotone??

Comment: @Mary: Absolutely. You can show that if $x<\alpha$, then $x<f(x)<\alpha$, so $f(x)<f(f(x))<\alpha$, and so on, while if $x>\alpha$, then $x>f(x)>\alpha$, so $f(x)>f(f(x))>\alpha$, and so on. One of the two subsequences is below $\alpha$ and increasing, and the other is above $\alpha$ and decreasing. The slightly messy part is showing that if $x<\alpha$, then $f(x)<\alpha$, and if $x>\alpha$, then $f(x)>\alpha$, but it is just algebra.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Mary: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that $$\begin{align}a_{n+2} &= 1+\frac2{1+a_{n+1}}\\ &= 1+\cfrac2{1+\left(1+\frac2{1+a_n}\right)}\\ &= 1+\cfrac{2}{2+\frac2{1+a_n}}\\ &= 1+\cfrac1{1+\frac1{1+a_n}}\\ &= 1+\frac{1+a_n}{(1+a_n)+1}\\ &= 1+\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}\\ &= \frac{3+2a_n}{2+a_n},\end{align}$$ and so $$a_{n+2}-a_n=\frac{3+2a_n}{2+a_n}-a_n=\frac{-a_n^2+3}{2+a_n}$$

Then we can conclude that $a_{n+2}>a_n$ if we know that $0<a_n<\sqrt 3,$ and we can conclude that $a_{n+2}<a_n$ if we know that $a_n>\sqrt3.$

There are a few cases to consider, then:

- If $a_1>\sqrt3,$ then you'll want to show that $a_{2k-1}>\sqrt3$ and $0<a_{2k}<\sqrt 3$ for all $k.$ (Proceed by induction on $k$.) What, then, can you conclude about the monotonicity of the two subsequences?
- If $0<a_1<\sqrt3,$ then you'll want to show that $0<a_{2k-1}<\sqrt3$ and $a_{2k}>\sqrt 3$ for all $k.$ What, then, can you conclude about the monotonicity of the two subsequences?
- I'll let you figure out how to handle the $a_1=\sqrt3$ case.

Comment: Could you tell me why we take these two terms, $a_{n+2}$ and $a_{n}$??

Comment: That is because the terms of the subsequence are two apart in the original sequence. For example, the sequence of terms of the form $a_{2k-1}$ are $a_1,a_3,a_5,a_7,a_9,$ and so on. So, if $a_n$ is a general term of that subsequence, then the next one will be $a_{n+2}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!!